# How to get value in Django without POST or GET SIMILAR to FLASK request.args.get

Tags: python, django, request

how to get request.args.get in Django without changing url.py and no passing an argument/variable through def index(request, NO__EXTRA_VARIABLE_HERE) it is possible to get value without POST or GET form? What I can use to get this value in Django?

I tried:
request.GET but then I get WSGI Error

or

```
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'index' with keyword arguments '{'currency_type': 'usa'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['\\Z']
<a href="{% url 'index' currency_type=item.currency_type %}" class="btn btn-outline-primary {{item.active}}" role="button">{{item.display_text}}</a>
```

FLASK CODE

index.html in flask app

```
<div class="card-footer text-center">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url_for('movie_details', movie_id=movie.id) }}">Show more</a>
</div>
```

```
 @app.route('/')
def homepage():

    selected_list = request.args.get('list_type', "popular")


    buttons = [
        {"list_type": "now_playing", "active": "", "display_text": "now playing"},
        {"list_type": "popular", "active": "", "display_text": "popular"},
        {"list_type": "upcoming", "active": "", "display_text": "upcoming"},
        {"list_type": "top_rated", "active": "", "display_text": "top rated"},
        {"list_type": "favorites", "active": "", "display_text": "favorites"},
    ]

    if selected_list not in ["now_playing", "upcoming", "top_rated","favorites"]:
        selected_list = "popular"""


    for button in buttons:
        if button['list_type'] == selected_list:
            button['active'] = 'active'

    if selected_list =="favorites":
        favorite_list = show_favorite()
        list_of_favorites = [get_single_movie(i) for i in favorite_list]
        if not favorite_list:
            flash("You dont have favorites movies", "alert-danger")
            return redirect(url_for("homepage"))
        return render_template("homepage.html",current_list=selected_list,buttons=buttons, list_of_favorites=list_of_favorites)

    else:
        movies = tmdb_client.get_movies(how_many=8, list_type=selected_list)
        return render_template("homepage.html",current_list=selected_list,buttons=buttons, movies=movies)
```

What I tried to do in Django:

```
def index(request):
    
    selected_currency_type = request.GET.get('currency_type', "usa")
    buttons = [
            {"currency_type": "usa", "active": "", "display_text": "USD"},
            {"currency_type": "euro", "active": "", "display_text": "Euro"},
            {"currency_type": "cny", "active": "", "display_text": "Chinese Yuan"},
            {"currency_type": "jpy", "active": "", "display_text": "Japanese Yen"},
        ]
    for button in buttons:
        if button['currency_type'] == selected_currency_type:
            button['active'] = 'active'

    currecies_list = load_currencies(selected_currency_type)
    context = {
                "user": request.user,
                "currecies_list": currecies_list,
                "buttons" : buttons,
                    }
    return render(request, "web/index.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create the get request in this way:

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}?currency_type={{item.currency_type}}"
```

in other words: split the url and parameter generation meaning pass the parameter not as part of the path but as parameters after the ?

In this way, the parameter is not part of the path and will not affect your url-pattern in urls.py. But the parameters are still in the request object and via that accessible in the view.